# Count string occurences in file

Tags: shell

I am trying to count the occurence of a particular line in a file using shell script. The content of the file is:

> Mon Dec 23 06:21:00 2019 [pid 3294] [ftpuser] FTP response: Client "127.0.0.1", "230 Login successfull."
>
> Mon Dec 23 06:21:00 2019 [pid 3294] [ftpuser] FTP response: Client "127.0.0.1", "230 Login successfull."
>
> Mon Dec 23 06:21:00 2019 [pid 3294] [ftpuser] FTP response: Client "127.0.0.1", "230 Login successfull."
>
> Mon Dec 23 06:21:00 2019 [pid 3294] [ftpuser] FTP response: Client "127.0.0.1", "230 Login successfull."

The shell script code is:

```
file="vsftpd1.log"
count=0
while read str; do
  echo $str
  if [[ $str == *"230 Login successfull."* ]]; 
  then 
      count=$((count+1))
  fi
done < $file
echo $count
```

The output of the last line should be four. I have noticed that if condition is executing only one time. But it should run four times. Please help me to find mistake in the code, if any.
Thankxx in advance!

Comment: Works fine here, I can't reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify that with `grep` (match occurences) and its `-c` (count occurences).

```
#!/bin/sh
file=vsftpd1.log
grep -c '230 Login successfull.' "$file"
```

If you need to capture the number into a variable:

```
count=$(grep -c '230 Login successfull.' "$file")
echo $count
```

Comment: Actually this is my very first day with shell script and I don't know anything about it. Would you please tell me where to use the second  line of your solution in my code??

Comment: grep has `-c` switch, wc is not needed

Comment: It is still giving one. I have used this line inside the loop!

Comment: @VipulTyagi you do not need the loop - the commands do the file reading themselves

Comment: @oguzismail you are absolutely right :) I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That entire (rather inefficient) snippet of code can be replaced with the much simpler:

```
count=$(grep -c '230 Login successfull.' vsftpd1.log)
echo ${count}
```

As more explanation, `grep -c` returns the line count of the lines that match your search pattern. There is no need for a `bash`-based loop which reads one line at a time and checks the pattern - this is likely to be much faster in the `grep` executable.

---

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax:~$ grep '230 Login successfull.' qq.in
Mon Dec 23 06:21:00 2019 [pid 3294] [ftpuser] FTP response: Client "127.0.0.1", "230 Login successfull."
Mon Dec 23 06:21:00 2019 [pid 3294] [ftpuser] FTP response: Client "127.0.0.1", "230 Login successfull."
Mon Dec 23 06:21:00 2019 [pid 3294] [ftpuser] FTP response: Client "127.0.0.1", "230 Login successfull."
Mon Dec 23 06:21:00 2019 [pid 3294] [ftpuser] FTP response: Client "127.0.0.1", "230 Login successfull."

pax:~$ count=$(grep -c '230 Login successfull.' qq.in) ; echo ${count}
4
```

Comment: Nope, still giving one!! help me out please

Comment: I don't have problem with large code. But it should work

Comment: @VipulTyagi: if it's only giving one then I would suggest that only one line has the pattern. My advice is to re-check the file content, since it works fine according to the transcript I added. And you really *should* have a problem with large (and, just as importantly, inefficient) code, that's what being an artisan is all about, taking pride in your work product :-)